# Unnecessary download when upgrading to 16.10

Tags: apt, 16.04, upgrade, package-management, 16.10

I'm currently using 16.04 LTS and would like to upgrade to 16.10. Download size is 3.2GB for me. When I looked into the "to be upgraded" packages, there's `0ad` game.

Currently on 16.04, its version is 0.0.20 (alpha 20) and [no newer version is released yet](https://play0ad.com/download/). So, why is this *large* package (~1.5GB) listed in "upgrade" package list? (**Question 1**)

**Question 2:** If I hold this package (using `apt-mark hold`), can I play the game when I finished upgrading to 16.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe new versions haven't been released, but [the package did get a bump](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=0ad):

- xenial (16.04LTS) (games): Real-time strategy game of ancient warfare [universe] 
  0.0.20-1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386
- yakkety (16.10) (games): Real-time strategy game of ancient warfare [universe] 
  0.0.20-3: amd64 arm64 armhf i386

The [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/0/0ad/0ad_0.0.20-3/changelog) has this to say:

```
0ad (0.0.20-3) unstable; urgency=medium

  * Add debian/patches/fix-gcc6-segfault.patch to fix spidermonkey segfault
    when built with gcc6. (Closes: #835176)
  * Temporarily disable test suite on arm64 to fix arch-specific FTBFS.
  * Call dh_strip --dbgsym-migration to cleanly migrate from the old -dbg
    package to -dbgsym.

 -- Vincent Cheng <vcheng@debian.org>  Wed, 07 Sep 2016 22:44:22 -0700

0ad (0.0.20-2) unstable; urgency=medium

  * Team upload.
  * Drop 0ad-dbg package and use the automatic -dbgsym package instead.
  * d/rules: Remove override for dh_builddeb because xz is the default
    compression.
  * Declare compliance with Debian Policy 3.9.8.
  * Build-depend on python and fix FTBFS.
    Thanks to Lucas Nussbaum for the report. (Closes: #832870)
  * Ensure that 0ad can be built twice in a row by updating dh_auto_clean
    target. Thanks to Peter Green for the patch.

 -- Markus Koschany <apo@debian.org>  Sun, 21 Aug 2016 04:54:55 +0200

0ad (0.0.20-1) unstable; urgency=medium

  * New upstream release.
    - Drop build-dep on libjpeg-dev.
    - Refresh patches.
  * Remove debian/menu file as per tech-ctte decision in #741573.
  * Update Standards version to 3.9.7, no changes required.
  * Update jQuery/JavaScript related lintian overrides.

 -- Vincent Cheng <vcheng@debian.org>  Sun, 03 Apr 2016 19:42:21 -0700
```

I suppose none of the changes affect gameplay, and your method might work. I'm not sure of that, though.